# Making a[href$=".xyz"] not display when <a> contains <img>

Tags: css

I have many hyperlinks like:

```
<a href="file.pdf">File</a>
```

and I use CSS to suffix the word PDF after each one of these links as follows:

```css
a[href$=".pdf"]:after {
content: "(pdf)"; 
font-size: 10px; 
color: #666; 
padding-left: 5px; 
vertical-align: 6%;
}
```

This works great for text hyperlinks but I do not want "(pdf)" to display for hyperlinked images such as:

```
<a href="file.pdf"><img src="" alt=""></a>
```

Any suggestions here?

Comment: You can't do it with the current versions of CSS (<=3). There's no way to control the parent element according to its children. You can ofcourse give the <a> tag a different class when it's containing an <img>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following css rule:

```
a[href$=".pdf"] :not(img):after {
   content: "(pdf)";
   font-size: 10px;
   color: #666;
   padding-left: 5px;
   vertical-align: 6%;
}
```

See the JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/eh4jQ/4/

Comment: Very impressed by the simplicity of this solution.

Comment: @Oscar, this helps in some cases but not if the text link is not within <p></p> tags. For example <p>This is a <a href="file.pdf">test file</a></p>.

Comment: Agreed, though the tradeoff with doing this in css is either using a wrapper tag for the text, or using classes such as in the answer posted by @godfrzero. Note that you're not just limited to p tags as the wrapper either. jQuery provides a :has selector, which would make this possible to do without any kind of wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want to append the text after the anchor, and not the child: I don't think there's a way to change the parents style based on children, so you can add a class to the anchors that have images?

Try the following HTML:

```
<a href="file.pdf" class="someClass"><img src="" alt=""></a>
<a href="file.pdf" >File</a>
```

And the following CSS:

```
a[href$=".pdf"]:not(.someClass):after {
    content: "(pdf)";
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #666;
    padding-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: 6%;
}
```

This should only add the `:after` pseudo-element to the anchors without `someClass`